# Ideal way to enrich a KStream with lookup data

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

My stream has a column called 'category' and I have additional static metadata for each 'category' in a different store, it gets updated once every couple of days. What is the right way to do this lookup? There are two options with Kafka streams

1. Load static data outside of Kafka Streams and just use `KStreams#map()` to add metadata. This is possible as Kafka Streams is just a library.
2. Load the metadata to a Kafka topic, load it to a `KTable` and do `KStreams#leftJoin()`, this seems more natural and leaves partitioning etc to Kafka Streams. However, this requires us to keep the `KTable` loaded with all the values. Note that we would have to load the entire lookup data, and not just the changes.

   - For example, say initially there was just one category 'c1'. Kafka streams app was stopped gracefully, and restarted again. After the restart, a new category 'c2' was added. My assumption is that, table = KStreamBuilder().table('metadataTopic') would just have the value 'c2', as that was the only thing that changed since the app started for second time. I would want it to have 'c1' and 'c2'.
   - If it does have 'c1' as well, would the data ever be removed from KTable (perhaps by setting sending key = null message ? ) ?

Which of the above is the right way to lookup metadata?

Is it possible to always force just one stream to be read from the beginning on restarts, this is so that all the metadata can be loaded into `KTable`.

Is there another way using stores?

Comment: If one of the answers below addressed your question, please mark it as Accepted.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> 1. Load static data outside of Kafka Streams and just use KStreams#map() to add metadata. This is possible as Kafka Streams is just a library.

This works.  But usually people opt for the next option you listed, because the side data to enrich the input stream with is typically not fully static; rather, it is changing but somewhat infrequently:

> 2. Load the metadata to a Kafka topic, load it to a KTable and do KStreams#leftJoin(), this seems more natural and leaves partitioning etc to Kafka Streams. However, this requires us to keep the KTable loaded with all the values. Note that we would have to load the entire lookup data, and not just the changes.

This is the usual approach, and I'd recommend to stick to it unless you have a specific reason not to.

> However, this requires us to keep the KTable loaded with all the values. Note that we would have to load the entire lookup data, and not just the changes.

So I guess you also prefer the second option, but you are concerned about whether or not this is efficient.

Short answer is: Yes, the KTable will be loaded with all the (latest) values per key.  The table will contain the entire lookup data, but keep in mind that the KTable is partitioned behind the scenes:  if, for example, your input topic (for the table) has `3` partitions, then you can run up to `3` instances of your application, each of which getting `1` partition of the table (assuming data is spread evenly across partitions, then each partition/shared of the table would hold about 1/3 of the table's data).  So in practice more likely than not it "just works".  I share more details below.

**Global KTables:** Alternatively, you can use [global KTables](https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/concepts.html#globalktable) instead of the (paritioned) normal table variant. With global tables every instance of your application has a full copy of the table data. This makes global tables very useful for join scenarios, including for enriching a KStream as per your question.

> Is it possible to always force just one stream to be read from the beginning on restarts, this is so that all the metadata can be loaded into KTable.

You don't need to worry about that. Simply put, if there is no local "copy" of the table available, then the Streams API would automatically ensure that the table's data is read fully from scratch.  If there is a local copy available, then your application will re-use that copy (and update its local copy whenever new data is available in the table's input topic).

**Longer answer with examples**

Imagine the following input data (think: changelog stream) for your `KTable`, note how this input consists of `6` messages:

```
(alice, 1) -> (bob, 40) -> (alice, 2) -> (charlie, 600), (alice, 5), (bob, 22)
```

And here's the various states of the "logical" `KTable` that would result from this input is, where each newly received input message (such as `(alice, 1)`) would result in a new state of the table:

```
Key      Value
--------------
alice   |   1    // (alice, 1) received

 |
 V

Key      Value
--------------
alice   |   1
bob     |  40    // (bob, 40) received

 |
 V

Key      Value
--------------
alice   |   2    // (alice, 2) received
bob     |  40

 |
 V

Key      Value
--------------
alice   |   2
bob     |  40
charlie | 600    // (charlie, 600) received

 |
 V

Key      Value
--------------
alice   |   5    // (alice, 5) received
bob     |  40
charlie | 600

 |
 V

Key      Value
--------------
alice   |   5
bob     |  22    // (bob, 22) received
charlie | 600
```

What you can see here is that, even though the input data may have many, many messages (or "changes" as you said; here, we have `6`), the number of entries/rows in the resulting `KTable` (which is undergoing continuous mutations based on the newly received input) is the number of unique keys in the input (here: starting out with `1`, ramping up to `3`), which typically is significantly less than the number of messages. So, if the number of messages in the input is `N` and the number of unique keys for these messages is `M`, then typically `M << N` (`M` is significantly smaller than `N`; plus, for the record, we have the invariant `M <= N`).

This is the first reason why "this requires us to keep the KTable loaded with all the values" is typically not an issue, because only the latest value is retained per key.

The second reason that helps is that, as Matthias J. Sax has pointed out, Kafka Streams uses RocksDB as the default storage engine for such tables (more precisely: the state stores that back a table).  RocksDB allows you to maintain tables that are larger than the available main memory / Java heap space of your application because it can spill to local disk.

Lastly, the third reason is that a `KTable` is partitioned.  So, if your input topic for the table is (say) configured with `3` partitions, then what's happening behind the scenes is that the `KTable` itself is partitioned (think: sharded) in the same way.  In the example above, here's what you could end up with, though the exact "splits" depend on the how the original input data is spread across the partitions of the table's input topic:

Logical KTable (last state of what I showed above):

```
Key      Value
--------------
alice   |   5
bob     |  22
charlie | 600
```

Actual KTable, partitioned (assuming `3` partitions for the table's input topic, plus keys=usernames being spread evenly across partitions):

```
Key      Value
--------------
alice   |   5    // Assuming that all data for `alice` is in partition 1

Key      Value
--------------
bob     |  22    // ...for `bob` is in partition 2

Key      Value
--------------
charlie | 600    // ...for `charlie` is in partition 3
```

In practice, this partitioning of the input data -- among other things -- allows you to "size" the actual manifestations of a KTable.

Another example:

- Imagine the latest state of your KTable would typically have a size of 1 TB (again, the approximate size is a function of the number of unique message keys in the table's input data, multiplied by the average size of the associated message value).
- If the table's input topic has only a `1` partition, then the KTable itself also has only `1` partition, with a size of 1 TB.  Here, because the input topic has but `1` partition, you could run your application with up to `1` app instances (so not really a whole lot of parallelism, heh).
- If the table's input topic has `500` partitions, then the KTable has `500` partitions, too, with a size of ~ 2 GB each (assuming data is evenly spread across the partitions).  Here, you could run your application with up to `500` app instances.  If you were to run exactly `500` instances, then each app instance would get exactly `1` partition/shard of the logical KTable, thus ending up with 2 GB of table data;  if you were to run only `100` instances, then each instance would get `500 / 100 = 5` partitions/shards of the table, ending up with about `2 GB * 5 = 10 GB` of table data.

Comment: What happens when the input stream has several partitions, metadata stream has just one partition, and there are several instances of the app? Would the each instance of the app load the metadata stream, or would one of them load it and others would somehow get the value from that instance?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the great answer. In the case that you want to join this KTable with a stream, how do you make sure that the partition you get from the KTable contains the data needed to join with the stream? You must ensure that they share the same key ?

Comment: Yes, the join requires that both the stream and the table have the same key.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. Now what would happen if the events in the stream contains multiple fields that each require a lookup (or more) in a different KTable? We would need to do a join, re-key the stream and proceed? Would this approach perform reasonably in your opinion? Thanks a lot for your insights :)

Comment: What you suggest is one option. Another option is to read the various tables into GlobalKTables, which you can join to your stream without needing to have the same key on both sides. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45975755/what-are-the-differences-between-ktable-vs-globalktable-and-leftjoin-vs-outerj.

Answer (score 6):

Your overall observation is correct and it depends what tradeoffs are more important for you. If you metadata is small, option 1 seems to be the better one. If metadata is big, it seems option 2 is the way to go.

If you use `map()`, you need to have a complete copy of your metadata in each application instance (as you cannot know exactly how Streams will partition you `KStream` data). Thus, if your metadata does not fit into main-memory using `map()` would not work easily.

If you use `KTable`, Streams will take care that metadata is sharded correctly over all running application instances, such that no data duplication is required. Furthermore, a `KTable` uses RocksDB as state store engine and thus can spill to disk.

**EDIT BEGIN**

About having all data in `KTable`: if you have two categories for the same key, the second value would overwrite the first value if you read the data directly from the topic into a `KTable` via `builder.table(...)` (changelog semantics). However, you can work around this easily by reading the topic as a record stream (ie, `builder.stream(...)` and apply an aggregation to compute the `KTable`. Your aggregation would simply emit a list of all values for each key.

About deleting: `KTable` uses changelog semantics and does understand tombstone message to delete key-value pairs. Thus, if you read a `KTable` from a topic and the topic contains a `<key:null>` message, the current record in `KTable` with this key will get deleted. This is harder to achieve when the `KTable` is a result of an aggregation, because an aggregation input record with `null` key or `null` value will simply get ignored and does not update the aggregation result.

The workaround would be to add a `map()` step before the aggregation and introduce a `NULL` value (ie, an user defined "object" that represents the tombstone but is not `null` -- in your case, you could call it a `null-category`). In your aggregation, you just return a `null` value as aggegation result if the input record has `null-category` as value. This will then translate in a tombstone message for your `KTable` and delete the current list of categories for this key.

**EDIT END**

And of course you can always build a custom solution via Processor API. However, if DSL can give you want you need, there is no good reason to do this.

Comment: Updated the question with examples for loading entire lookup data. I might have misunderstood what a KTable holds, will wait for your update).

Answer (score 0):

From Kafka 0.10.2.0, released in Feb 2017, the `GlobalKTable` concept is probably a better option to enrich a stream with lookup data.

https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/concepts.html#globalktable