# Kafka Streams: How to enrich multiple fields in nested objects with one-to-many relations

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have the situation where I need to enrich multiple (15) fields with additional data.

The data is looks like this

```java
class Company
    String abbreviation "abc"
    String fullName "<to be enriched by looking up via abbreviation>"
    List<Emloyee> employees;
    List<Department> departments;

class Employee
    String surname;
    String lastname;
    int someKey
    String someKeyEnriched "<to be enriched by looking up via someKey>"
    int secondKey
    String secondKeyEnriched "<to be enriched by looking up via secondKey>"

class Department
    int anotherKey
    String anotherKeyEnriched "<to be enriched by looking up via someKey>"
```

We implemented a service with Kafka streams. It reads the entries from the company topic and enriches data from additional topics.

The additional enrichment topics have entries with avro messages as value, like code="String", name="String" and additional fields. Eg: "abc", "The full name of company abc".
There are 15 enrichment topics and they get updated by another process every few months. The data is small enough to be hold in memory (> 1 mio).

We found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41029748/ideal-way-to-enrich-a-kstream-with-lookup-data) regarding whether holding these enrichment key values in a plain map, or joining them with the stream - and went for the cheap solution by using the map.

Code was quite easy and data enrichment looked something like:

```java
Topology.java ...

    final var stream = streamsBuilder.stream("NotYetEnrichedCompany", Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), new CompanySerde()));
    Produced<String, Company> companyStream = KafkaStreamsConfig.createCompanyProduced();
    stream
      .mapValues(companyEnricher::enrich)
      .to("EnrichedCompany", companyStream);


public class CompanyEnricher implements KeyValueEnricher<Company> {

  @Autowired
  private EnrichmentService enrichmentService;

  @Override
  public Company enrich(final Company company) {
    enrichAbbreviation(company);
    enrichEmployees(company);
    enrichDepartments(company);
    return company;
  }

  private void enrichEmployees(final Company company) {
    for (final var employee : company.getEmployees()) {
      enrichSomeKey(employee);
      enrichSecondKey(employee);
    }
  }

  private void enrichSomeKey(final Employee employee) {
    final var key = employee.getSomeKey();
    enrichmentService.get("SomeKeyTopic", code).ifPresent(employee::setSomeKeyEnriched);
  }

...

}
```

We were happy - until we realized, that the data enrichment did not work for the earliest company entries. 
This happened when the processing of company entries started, before the reading of enrichment data was done.
This was also mentioned in the stack overflow question above.

Then we wanted to rewrite it, using the kafka streams join method, to ensure that we use always the most actual data when enriching data.
Code gets complicated:

```java
Topology.java ...

companyAbbreviationTable = streamsBuilder.globalTable("company.abbreviation", consumed);
employeeAbbreviationTable = streamsBuilder.globalTable("employee.abbreviation", consumed);
...

    final var stream = streamsBuilder.stream("NotYetEnrichedCompany", Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), new CompanySerde()));
    Produced<String, Company> companyStream = KafkaStreamsConfig.createCompanyProduced();
    stream
      .leftJoin(companyAbbreviationTable,
        (companyId, company) -> company.getAbbreviation(),
        (company, fullName) -> {
          if (fullName != null) {
            company.setMachineTypeMds(name.get("name").toString());
          }
          return company;
        })
      .flatMapValues(Company::getEmployees)
      .leftJoin(employeeAbbreviationTable,
        (employeeId, employee) -> employee.getSomeKey(),
        (employee, fullName) -> {
          if (fullName != null) {
            employee.setSomeKeyEnriched(name.get("name").toString());
          }
          return employee;
        })
    // Question 1: How can I get the surrounding company object again to persist it in the "EnrichedCompany" stream?
      .to("EnrichedCompany", companyStream);
```

If I have to replace 15 values with join, the code gets quite big and its testablilty is quite hard.

**Question 1:** How can I get the initial company instance back, after iterating over employees:
`.flatMapValues(Company::getEmployees)` to stream the enriched company instance `.to("EnrichedCompany", companyStream);`

**Question 2:** 
I also found kafkas [interactive queries](https://kafka.apache.org/10/documentation/streams/developer-guide/interactive-queries.html#querying-local-key-value-stores)

Is it correct that with interactive queries I could reference 15 ReadOnlyKeyValueStore in my CompanyEnricher class and use the initial solution again?

```
    stream
      .mapValues(companyEnricher::enrich)
      .to("EnrichedCompany", companyStream);
```

And will interactive queries solve my initial problem, so that the enrichment of the companys is done with the most actual data?

**Question 3:** 
Is there a better pattern for data enrichment in my situation?